# Crystallographic group property

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, geometry, group-actions, isometry

I'm studying on the article "A Geometric proof of Bieberbach's theorems on crystallographic groups".

G is called n-dimensional crystallographic group if it's a discrete subgroup of $Isom(\mathbb{R}^n)$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with compact fundamental domain.

[image]

I don't understand the first statement of this proposition.
I'm assuming it's a consequence of the discreteness, but I can't find a way to prove it.

Comment: I agree the first statement captures discreteness. And since the whole thing is a definition of a term, you don't prove that in general. You may want to prove that a specific group has these properties. Is that what you're asking? What specific group do you have in mind?

Comment: any crystallographic group has these properties, i'm asking how to prove the first

Comment: But this looks like a definition rather than a proposition. If that is the case, you can't prove it. Or are you asking why this is equivalent to  the definition you gave?

Comment: There is no proposition here.

Answer (score 1):

Note that any bounded infinite set has a limit point therefore cannot be discrete. In particular the hypersphere of radius $t$ centered at $a$ is bounded so it may only intersect with finitely many cosets or $G$ would have a limit point.